# In HTTPS mode FB.XFBML.parse on fb:profile-pic makes HTTP links to images

Tags: facebook, https

FB.XFBML.parse in HTTPS mode makes HTTP links to images (not HTTPS). Is this bug of FB.XFBML.parse? What can I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem by using GraphAPI Pictures links http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/. It has special parameter return_ssl_resources=1 for HTTPS protocol.
So I use https://graph.facebook.com/facebook_id/picture?return_ssl_resources=1 link.